# CSS - Padding in IE issue?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, padding

I'm having trouble width some padding. In Chrome/Firefox it looks different than in Internet Explorer. In Internet Explorer it is much bigger. It is the

```
.menu ul li{
    display:inline;
    padding-right:60px;
    margin:0;
}
```

Why?

```
.menu{
    background-color:#000;
    height:35px;
    padding-top:15px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:18px;
}

.menu ul{
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.menu ul li{
    display:inline;
    padding-right:60px;
    margin:0;
}

.menu a:link{
    color:#fff;
}

.menu a:active{
    color:#fff;
}

.menu a:hover{
    color:#fff;
}

.menu a:visited{
    color:#fff;
}
```

I really hope someone can help :)

Comment: can you make your code in fiddle/

Answer (score 3):

IE calculates padding as part of height/width, other browsers interpret it height/width plus padding. So try to give only height/width or padding/margin.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to unify the box model of ie with those of other browsers you can always use the 
box-sizing CSS3 property.
it is not supported in older version of ie, so it's best to use border-box in chrome, ff, etc. than to use content-box for ie.
for further reading look here -
http://www.css3.info/preview/box-sizing/

Answer (score 0):

Because the different browser have different font styling even though you set the font-styling. Similarly ie have different front size. so you can write the code for IE.

Here the link to help how to specific css in ie only.

http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/