# CSS/HTML IE doesn't leave margin on the right right side in bootstrap button

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm compleatly begginer in CSS and I don't understand why in Chrome/Firefox/Safari I have correct styling for bootstrap button like here - https://monosnap.com/file/leLdh4XFNlzBoXbA2xHuvnW7nGDHMH and somehow it's different in IE - https://monosnap.com/file/tuNAlM5MsJm6U80Z1TAR1uu9frN0SN

**styling.scss**

```
&__button {
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 4.8rem;
  justify-content: center;
  letter-spacing: .7px;
  line-height: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18.4rem;

  &-overview {
    background-color: $c-blue;
    color: $c-white;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    width: max-content;
  }
}
```

**button.html.erb**

```
<div class="text-center">
  <%= link_to t('.bank_to_employees_overview'), bank_employees_path, class: "bank-employee__button bank-employee__button-overview" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to add padding with the class `.px-3` instead of adding it with `&-overview { padding: 0 1.5rem;}`.

Comment: Heh... if I add `.px-3` and delete `padding` from `.overview` it will works on IE but in other browsers I will have something like this - https://monosnap.com/file/320x1g7mUM6p4jr0sCAovVP8WNhfvk

Comment: Is that all that is in your button.html.erb file? Is it a partial and if so how are you rendering it?

Comment: @Jake nope, it's inside another `div class="container"`. This is not a partial, besides this button there is only confirmation text as you see in the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from this topic fixed the issue [CSS - Padding in IE issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288991/css-padding-in-ie-issue)

> IE calculates padding as part of height/width, other browsers interpret it height/width plus padding. So try to give only height/width or padding/margin.

So if I delete `width` and `padding` plus add `.px-3` like @Jeremy suggested in the comments it will works as expected on all browsers